# Can't seem to bind two text inputs together

Tags: jquery, html, bind

I have two form inputs that I need have matching field content. Meaning if I enter text in one field it is the exact same on the other field (they are in separate forms).

I thought I could use .bind() to do it but my script would not allow my text to bind to another input.

```
var inp = $("#text1");

if ("onpropertychange" in inp)
inp.attachEvent($.proxy(function () {
    if (event.propertyName == "value")
        $("div").text(this.value);
}, inp));
 else
  inp.addEventListener("input", function () { 
    $("#text2").text(this.value);
}, false);



<input type="text" id="text1" />
<input type="text" id="text2" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change `keyup` to `change` if you don`t want to edit it letter by letter; [jsfiddle there](http://jsfiddle.net/R9AHd/)

```
var $inputs = $('#input1, #input2');

$inputs.keyup(function(){
    $inputs.val($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$("#text1").change({
  $("#text2").val(this.val());
});
```

Comment: +1 for short and simple way just note it won't be "live" i.e. as the user type in one box, the other won't get updated until user get out of the first box.

Comment: if you want it to be "live", just change the `change` event to `keyup`

Comment: Yeah, but then you lose it when mouse is being used (paste, drag text) so combination of both would be the ideal solution. Up to the OP here to decide though.

Comment: Is there a way to mitigate the delay in text appearing in the second field?

Answer (score 0):

What about [this](http://jsfiddle.net/bmitchell/MvKUE/)?

```
$('#input01').keyup(function() {
    value = $(this).val();
    $("#input02").val(value);
});
```